# Некоректно выполняется javascript на сайте

Tags: javascript, html, dom

И так на сайте есть форма её нужно автоматически заполнять в одном android приложении программно т.е я через WebView отправляю js на сайт но проблема в том что поля Логин и Пароль не заполняются js скриптом вот форма

```
            <h4 class="modal-title">Зарегистрированный клиент</h4>
            <span></span>

            <div class="form-group required">
                <label class="control-label" for="input-email">Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" value="" id="input-email" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group required">
                <label class="control-label" for="input-password">Пароль</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" value="" id="input-password" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary loginaccount" data-loading-text="Загрузка...">Войти</button>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <a href="http://girbar.tj/forgot-password/">Забыли пароль?</a>
            </div>
```

И через такой js хотел изменить поля login и пароля

```
document.getElementById("input-email").value = "java";
```

Но ничего не получается поле остаётся пустым

Comment: А по какому событию у Вас выполняется скрипт?

Comment: Пока только через консоль выполняю

Comment: ну, я в том смысле, что скрипт-то работает нормально, поле заполняется: http://jsfiddle.net/5aj7Ldc0/

Comment: Но вот почему-то на сайте этого не происходит

Comment: потому что на сайте он не выполняется, очевидно. я потому и спрашиваю: Вы его на сайте по какому событию запускаете?

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю. Но говорю что я сейчас скрипт выполняю через консоль

Comment: Какую консоль вы имеете в виду?

Comment: Браузерную в инспекторе

Comment: Посмотрите, может у вас контекст консоли не там. Должно быть top https://imgur.com/658gFCC.png

Comment: Вот один раз взгляните https://imgur.com/a/44n1BR9

Comment: Давайте ссылочку на сайт, попробую разобраться.

Comment: Все понял. У них на странице несколько элементов с `id="input-email"`. Делайте так `document.getElementsByName("email")[1]`

Comment: Спасибо сработало !